# Is there any package in R for conditional autoregressive range model (CARR)?

Tags: volatility, time-series, econometrics

I am working on a project which requires volatility estimation using range based volatility. Is there any package in R which helps me in estimating the CARR model proposed by Chou (2005).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to quant.SE! I do not have specific experience with the CARR Model, however, I had a short look in the paper you mentioned: As far as I understand the model specification you just implement a GARCH(p,q) estimation for the range $R_t:=\max{P_\tau}-\min{P_\tau}$ where $\tau=t-1,t-1+\frac{1}{n},\dots,t$ where $n$ is the number of intervals used in measuring the price. Instead of implementing GARCH for the returns $r_t$ you just compute the same for 
$$R_t=\lambda_t\varepsilon_t\\\lambda_t=\omega+\sum\alpha_iR_{t-1}+\sum\beta_i\lambda_{t-1}$$.
This is in line with Section 1.2 of the original paper, stating:

> A convenient property for CARR is the ease of estimation. Specifically, the QMLE
>   estimation of the CARR model can be obtained by estimating a GARCH model
>   with a particular specification: specifying a GARCH model for the square root of
>   range without a constant term in the mean equation

Therefore, to answer your question: Just compute a time-series $R_t$ of ranges and then run any package computing GARCH for you, for example [fGarch](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjj5q7P87DKAhWHORQKHSorANgQFgggMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fweb%2Fpackages%2FfGarch%2FfGarch.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEqTbcYmyqVKDiXeXkM4M6SD2ozBg&bvm=bv.112064104,d.d24&cad=rja).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try it as per your suggestion.